# How is the output of a neuron calculated from the bias and the weight? [Neural Network]

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am reading this online book: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com and according to it (in the First Chapter) the output of the neuron is calculated using this formula: 
[image]

but this does not add up in Chapter 3 http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html where we have this interactive animation: 
[image]

am I wrong by calculating the output by doing to following

-0.69 * 1 + (-0.69) which is equal to -1.38 and not the output in the example 0.20. Could somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong output function. You should be able to figure that out from the fact that what you've quoted only ever produces an output of 0 or 1. The output in th example you're looking at is not given by this simple threshold on/off function, but by taking the result of the sigmoid function with `w*x+b` as its argument. This is all described in [chapter 1](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html), including the definition of the sigmoid function:

```
sigmoid(z) = 1 / ( 1 + e^-z )
```

Put your -1.38 into that function and you get (approximately) 0.2.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, when I put my -1.38 in the function I am getting 0.8 and not 0.2. Am I doing the math wrong?

Comment: Figured it out. You missed a "-" in front of the z so -1.38 becomes positive and now I am getting 0.2. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for pointing out the missing minus sign, it's fixed now.